# How to add extra info in tooltips on Grafana Time Series dashboard based on SQL?

Tags: grafana

I have a database table T with 4 columns:
date, name, num_value, comment.

I can plot Grafana time series using this SQL:

```
select date, name, num_value as " " from T
```

and applying transformation: Prepare Time Series → Format → Multi-frame time series.
The tooltip shows (date, name, num_value).

I would like to add to tooltip the content of column “comment” in my table T.
How to do it?